# Libre , Increment test case number after 2 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, auto-increment, libreoffice

This should be easy but I have test cases that should increment by one after every two rows.

Picture attached of what I want it to look like, there must be a formula I can use to do this for me.

I've tried online but nothing is helping with what I need it to do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IvGr.png)

Attempted - ="TC"&IF(A6=A5,A6+1,A6)

and got [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eCtl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cell 1 containing 1 and cellA2 containing 1, try this in cell A3 and drag down :

```
=IF(A2=A1,A2+1,A2)
```

I didn't use your complete name but you could use the ampersand for that part :

```
="TXT"&IF(A2=A1,A2+1,A2)
```

After me making an error, this works :

```
="TC"&IF(MID(A2,3,10)=MID(A1,3,10),MID(A2,3,10)+1,MID(A2,3,10))
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work the way I want - Added an image of what I got when I attempted it. I need each row to be prefixed with one 'TC'

Comment: Apologies, brain not in gear, try this : ="TC"&IF(MID(A2,3,10)=MID(A1,3,10),MID(A2,3,10)+1,MID(A2,3,10))